# Does a pointer point to something when initialized with NULL?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I was solving a problem involving binary tree in leetcode.com. There I found a structure of a binary tree which I could not comprehend properly. Here is the structure of the binary tree.

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
```

Now my question is, if I initialize a Treenode object "tree" with the following statement `TreeNode tree(17);`, will `tree.left` be a nullpointer, or will `tree.left` be another TreeNode object initialized with NULL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `left` and `right` will be `NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing *pointers* with *the things pointed to*.

In this case, `tree.left` can point to another TreeNode, but it cannot *be* another TreeNode. And immediately after the initialization of `tree`, it will be `NULL`.